# React Native Not Updating useState with setInterval

Tags: react-native, jsx

L01 should always be either Yes or No based on a query result returned. It starts out as 'No' and then as as soon as the query is checked it receives 'Yes'. However my return View does not update to Yes even though the setLevel01 value of it clearly shows 'Yes' in the console log. Any thoughts?

```
function DashScreen() {
let [L01, setLevel01 ] = useState('No');

useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => (
    setLevel01 = data.getlevels[0].level01,
    console.log("inside: ",setLevel01)
  ), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
});

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GetLevelsQuery)

   if (loading) return 'Loading...'
   if (error) return 'Something Bad Happened'
   console.log("outside: ",L01);

  return (
      <View><Text>{L01}</Text></View>
  );}
```

Comment: `setLevel01` is a function that takes updated state as a param. So use it like that: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setLevel01` is a function use to set the new state value. Try this:

```js
function DashScreen() {
    const [L01, setLevel01 ] = useState('No');

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => (
            setLevel01(data.getlevels[0].level01)
        ), 1000);

        return () => {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
    });

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GetLevelsQuery)

    if (loading) {
        return <Text>'Loading...'</Text>;
    }

    else if (error) {
        return <Text>'Something Bad Happened'</Text>;
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{L01}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: This updates correctly inside of the View now however if the data in the database changes to from 'Yes' to 'No' again it does not change back. Any thoughts?